# Strange behavior "find command" while using +mtime , +mmin options

Tags: linux, command-line, rhel

I have one production server. On that I have 1 directory for particular object, which will keep piling up the files after it gathered from different network nodes. So it have the files in subdirectories from May-2021 . It generally creates hourly subdirectories for a day and pushed the files into those subdirectories.
Subdirectory structure -

[image]

I have used the following command `find . -type f -mtime +2 | xargs ls -ltr`  to list out the files which are 2 days older to get them deleted.

but when I ran the command to check I found that they are sorted in unexpected way.

[image]

As you can see above, ideally it should short 10-03 files then 11-03 ,but its doing exactly opposite. Another thing is it also listing the current day file(18-03).
So can someone shade some light on it?

Please note that directory size is 11G . And files generally be keep piling up in every minute ,so does it has any effect on this ?

**Distro** - **Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.6 (Maipo)**

Comment: Please [don't post pictures of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/100397)

Comment: `ctime` is not creation time. It's inode (metadata) change time

Comment: Ok.. will keep in mind.Motive was to show that how directories are structured and what output was generated after executing & I used  mtime , ctime , mmin ,but all three produced same output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`find . -ctime +2` reports the files whose *last change status time* is 3 days old or older (where the difference between the time `find` was started and the ctime of the file, rounded down to an integer number of days is strictly greater than 2).

The `ctime`, which you can print with `ls -lc` is updated any time anything about the file is modified (except when its just its access time): when its entry in any directory is renamed, when it's (un)linked (from)to a new directory, when its contents or permissions or other metadata changes...

The timestamp that `ls -l` shows by default and that `ls -t` sorts on by default is the *last modification time*. That one is updated only when the contents is modified (though can also be set arbitrarily like with the `touch` command). That can be seen as the *creation time of the contents of the file*.

Beside those and the *last access time*, on some systems, there's also a *birth time* aka *creation time*, though it's generally less useful than the *last modification time*. With recent versions of GNU `ls` (not on your RHEL7 system), it can be displayed with `ls -l --time=birth` or `ls -l --time=creation`.

To find regular files that were last modified over 2 days ago, and pass them to `ls` so it lists them from oldest to newest, you'd do:

```
find . -type f -mtime +1 -exec ls -lrtd {} +
```

Don't use `xargs` which cannot process the output of `find` (other than with `find -print0 | xargs -r0...`).

Like `xargs` though, `find -exec cmd {} +` may run more than one instance of `cmd`, which would result in several independently  sorted batches of files on output.

To avoid that, you could use `zsh` and do:

```
autoload zargs
zargs -- ./**/*(D.m+1Om) -- ls -Uld
```

Or with GNU `xargs` to do the splitting:

```
print -rNC1 -- **/*(ND.m+1Om) | xargs -r0 ls -Uld --
```

(`-U` being a GNU `ls` extension to not sort (unnecessary as `zsh` already sorted them). You could replace with `-rt` with other `ls` implementations).

You could always try without splitting at all, but might run into the limit on the length or arguments+environment that can be passed to a command and see a *argument list too long* error:

```
ls -lrtd -- **/*(D.m+1oN)
```

If you can't install zsh, with GNU implementations of the `find`, `sort`, `sed`, `xargs` and `ls` utilities (as found on RHEL7) you could do something like:

```
find . -type f -mtime +1 -printf '%T@:%p\0' |
  LC_ALL=C sort -zn |
  LC_ALL=C sed -z 's/^[^:]*://' |
  xargs -r0 ls -Uld
```

Where we sort the files by mtime by hand by letting `find` print it as a number with `%T@`, use `sort -n` to sort it, `sed` to remove it and `xargs` to pass the list to as many `ls` invocations as needed each one being told not to bother sorting with `-U`. All done with NUL-delimited records so it can work with arbitrary file paths.

In any case, to remove those files, with GNU `find`, you'd just need to use its `-delete` predicate:

```
find . -type f -mtime +1 -delete
```

Comment: Hi ,thanks ...but still its not sorted the way it should..I do not have liberty to use "zsh".When I tried simple "ls -lrth" .Its sorted correctly but when I used your given find command (find . -type f -mtime +1 -exec ls -lrtd {} +),it still not sorted the way it should(means oldest to newest). So any thing which is missing ?

Comment: @GauravDubey, as I said, if there are many files `ls` will be run several times, so you'll have batches independently sorted. Hence the use of zsh globs and its sorting qualifier for the whole list to be sorted before it's passed to as many `ls` invocations as needed. If you can't install zsh for some obscure reason, see edit.

Comment: Hi Stephane.. looks like, "tcsh" shell doesn't have this LC_ALL as I tried to execute your edited part I got Command not found .                                                                       "find . -type f -mtime +1 -printf '%T@:%p\0' | LC_ALL=C sort -zn |LC_ALL=C sed -z 's/^[^:]*://' |xargs -r0 ls -Uld
LC_ALL=C: Command not found.
LC_ALL=C: Command not found.
"

Comment: @GauravDubey, not that's standard sh syntax (also works in rc-like shells), not csh syntax. You shouldn't be using (t)csh in this day and age. In csh, you'll need `env LC_ALL=C cmd`

Comment: yes..It worked perfectly in bash..Thanks a ton.